# apache redirect htacess on error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, centos5

Im trying to redirect on Error 500 , but its not happening.

.htaccess file

```
  ErrorDocument 500 /custom.php
```

custom.php just has a

```
  echo '<h1>ERROR OCCURED </h1>';
```

should I configure httpd.conf ? is there anything else that Im missing

my httpd.conf

```
     Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
    AllowOverride all
    Options IncludesNoExec
    AddOutputFilter Includes html
    AddHandler type-map var
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    LanguagePriority en es de fr
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you have AllowOverride enabled in the Virtual Hosts configuration?

Comment: Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride all
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

Comment: Is the .htaccess file in the /error/-catalog?

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not happening"? what response do you get?

Comment: same default http error 500 internal server

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enabled PHP parsing for this directory. You need to add the following to the `<Directory "/var/www/error">` stanza. E.g.

```
<Directory "/var/www/error">
...
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
...
</Directory>
```

Comment: to the <directory> ?

Comment: See updates to answer